# How to work with the X,Y Coordinates in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am trying with positioning my drawings at the right coordinate using touch screen. When i touch the screen I obtain the coordinates(x,y) but when i press my button to draw the circle it draws the circle at a location below the point i touched.I am using a relativeLyout as my layout, and i gave it an ID as "Layout" which I use to reference it in my java class.I thought it is because i am using the addView to draw on the same layout.I tried all my best to correct it but could not. (THE CIRCLE IS DRAWN AFTER CLICKING THE BUTTON BUT NOT AT THE POSITION I WANT IT, IT GOES BELOW THE POINT I TOUCHED)Can someone please help me.
Here is my code.

```
public class MyView extends View{

        float x ;
    float y ;
    int radius = 20;

    public MyView(Context context, float x, float y){

        super(context);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;


    }   //end constructor


    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

    }   //end onDraw


}   //end class MyView
```

Here is my  MAIN CLASS:

```
public class ButtonClickActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    RelativeLayout laying;
    Button button;
    MyView myView;

    private static float x=100;
    private static float y=100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button_click);

        laying = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.circle);


        //set listeners
        button.setOnClickListener(this);



    }   //end onCreate

    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.circle:

        myView = new MyView(this, x, y);
        laying.addView(myView);}
```

Here is the Touch event

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        int action = event.getAction();

        //get the type of action
        switch(action){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   //you have touch the screen
            x =  event.getX();
            y =  event.getY();
                       break
                 }
}
```

Here is the Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/layout" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/circle" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:text="Circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you miss is the size of the view. Your custom view doesn't know how much space it needs for the circle, and the default one is wrap content, so what is the minimal size? That's right: 0.

That's why you can't see anything. Either you set a size from outside of the view, or you measure it somehow yourself within the view and tell the parent view what size the view needs (and then check what the parent gives you and use it).

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) for more information about custom views.

Incidentally, it's not recommended to create the paint inside the onDraw, at least not in a way that recreates it each time it's called.

Comment: I can see the circle, but it is drawn at the right position that I touched. It usually increases the y-coordinate. Thank you for the advice on the placement of the paint class.Can you please give more suggestions or sample code that uses a custom view.

Comment: ok , how about those : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html http://www.jayway.com/2012/06/25/creating-custom-android-views-part-1-extending-standard-views-and-adding-new-xml-attributes/ http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/custom-view-in-android-paint-on-screen-graph-as-sample/ http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ExampleofhowtowriteacustomsubclassofView.htm